# SQL coalesce behaviour but in standard

Tags: sql, coalesce

So I have  a homework assignment to write some queries and I have to adhere to the 1999 SQL standard and I am not allowed to used functions such as IF and COALESCE, could anyone explain to me how something like coalesce works using standard SQL? I have tried doing some searching for something like this but can't find anything, as this is really stupid

Comment: Yeah but I can't use IF statements either

Comment: Can you use UNION and WHERE?

Comment: SQL-1999 Coalesce: http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-99.bnf.html#xref-COALESCE ??

Comment: Also: equivalent CASE statements: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COALESCE#COALESCE

Comment: a completely useless homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IFNULL(value, defaultValue)`

Reference:
http://oreilly.com/catalog/sqlnut/chapter/ch04.html